# Hazelcast addItemListener with spring autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I'm trying to create a hazelcast-spring application with listeners but with no success for now. When i try to autowire my `UserListener` is `null`.

```
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
    IQueue<Object> queue1 = hazelcastInstance.getQueue("q");
    queue1.addItemListener(new UserListener(), true);
    }
```

This is my main method and it's working ok when i add the item listener with new instance of UserListener class (my listener) but i need to use the spring autowired annotation because in the listener i have service->dao and i want everything to be autowired.Any ideas how can i accomplish this?
This is my whole code:

**Main Class:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
        IQueue<Object> queue1 = hazelcastInstance.getQueue("q");
        queue1.addItemListener(new UserListener(), true);
        }
```

**Listener Class:**

```
    @Component
    public class UserListener implements ItemListener<Object> {
    
        @Autowired
        private UserService userService;
    
        public void itemAdded(ItemEvent<Object> arg0) {
        if (arg0 != null) {
            try {
            userService.process(arg0);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
       }
    
        public void itemRemoved(ItemEvent<Object> item) {
        System.out.println("The item is removed succesfully");
        }
    }
```

**POM.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>hazelcastServer</groupId>
      <artifactId>hazelcastServer</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> 
    
    <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/>
        </parent>
      
      <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          </dependency>
     <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
             <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      
      
    </project>
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code

```
queue1.addItemListener(new UserListener(), true);
```

creates a new UserListener object bypassing Spring, so any fields annotated as `@Autowired` don't get instantiated.

You need to try

```
UserListener userListener = applicationContext.getBean(UserListener.class)
queue1.addItemListener(userListener, true);
```

It's probably worth checking if `userListener` object is null, as it might be the Spring component scanning hasn't found you class and created a @Bean, as component scanning can be selective on which packages it scans.

Comment: how should i initialize applicationContext?

Comment: When i'm trying like that:
```ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HazelcastServer.class);
UserListener userListener = context.getBean(UserListener.class);
```
It throws me :  
No qualifying bean of type 'com.test.app.listener.UserListener' available

Comment: @ВладимирГичев I'm afraid you need to dig it a bit deeper in Spring. I'd suggest you try first without the Spring magic, since your issue is now related to Spring, not Hazelcast